# How to remove mathematically cancelling values from array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My application is collecting a series of adjustments to budget values to try to reach a goal. So far, I'm collecting the adjustments into an array and totaling their values to show how much more needs to be cut to reach the goal:

```
const goal = 25;
let cutTotal = 0;
let remaining = 0;
let cuts = [];

function update (value) {
  // Values are numbers: -1, 1, 0.1, -0.1. This function gets called
  // when any update is made to a budget value.
  cuts.push(value);

  cutTotal = 0;
  cuts.forEach(function (value) {
    cutTotal += value;
  });

  remaining = goal - cutTotal;
}
```

This is working as expected, but I'm thinking there has to be a reasonably performant way to manage the length of the `cuts` array by removing values that are redundant. (Adding and subtracting 1 from the total doesn't change the total, so why store the values?)

Comment: Why store the cuts at all? Isn't `cutTotal` enough?

Comment: Any attempt to calculate and remove such values will likely be more processor-intensive than just not.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: On adjusting `cutTotal` directly, I encountered issues with adjustments falling outside of defined limits not shown in this summary. Collecting the adjustments and then totaling them seemed to solve the issue, but may not be strictly necessary.

Comment: _" I encountered issues with adjustments falling outside of defined limits not shown in this summary"_ -> Without more context, we can't really tell what can be done or not. From the info you gave us, it seems that you don't need to keep track of every single cut that was made. This really brings the question of why you need to store them at all. Also beware of premature optimization as mentioned above. If you don't experience any lag, put code readability and maintainability first. Only then, optimize if needed

Comment: First question is why do you need to store the values? Your other values are already starting at 0. Why not simply adjust those values on each function call?